# Angular.JS - Is it possible to have multiple views in a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to find out if you can have more than one html file in a directive and then depending on what you pass through the html tag it shows a different HTML layout.

This is something that is required for a accordion that I am building. We want to be able to re-use the directive but sometimes the html will be of a different layout.

So far I believe this can be done by the following:

`<accordion data-attr="layout('feedback')></accordion>`

Then in the Js check what has been passed and point the accodion to a different view.

The bit I'm unsure about is pointing the accordion directive to a different html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the `ng-include` directive in your template:

```
module.directive('accordion', function() {
  return {
    scope: { type: '&' },
    template: '<div ng-include="type()"></div>'
  };
});
```

Comment: Cheers, this has helped alot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your directive you can set your template to be a function that accepts the element and attributes.

```
.directive('accordion', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return 'layout-' + attr.type + '.html';
    }
  };
});
```

And use it like:

```
<accordion type="some-file"></accordion>
```